# How can one design (a deathstar) on a sphere?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, print-design, 3d

I'm trying to design a death star like image in 10 gores to be printed out as stickers and be applied on a perfect sphere.

I first tried to design a simple flat deathstar image:

[image]

And use a program that crops the image into 10 gores:

[image]

As you can see, if one would stick these gores on a sphere the image would be totally distorted, this can especially be seen on the circle but is present all over the image.

How can I design a image like the second image which is not distorted?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand, you **need** the distortion so things look correct when placed on the sphere.

Comment: Yes, but the distortion incorrect as you can see, this kind of distortion is meant to convert flat maps of the world (which are always distorted because the earth is round) into maps which can be applied on spheres.

Comment: Welcome to the world of 'projections.' You can't distort the shapes to fit within the gores and maintain the aspect ratio of the shape. Try putting the shape on a sphere and then cut the sphere into gores to flatten it and you'll appreciate the problem and get some idea of a solution.

Comment: Upvoted automatically as this post contains "Death Star"

Comment: Its a cylindrical projection. You can use any 3d app for this task, you can use any GIS application for the task. IT is possible tht you could use illustrator for this task dont know havent tried.

Comment: * Other stars are available

Comment: @Scott. No, because it is not being applied with an algorithm. It is stickers. It will look exactly as printed when applied.

Answer (score 3):

Try going the other way. It might be faster. It will be more accurate.

Draw your design on a "blank" globe.

Cover the globe with tracing paper. (Cut gores into a blank sheet of tracing paper. Wrap the globe using your cut template)

Sketch the DeathStar onto the paper cover of the globe.

Unwrap the paper cover "template" noting placement, shape and direction of the elements that seemed distorted in your initial attempt.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Definitely something I will try. Do you know how something like a soccer ball would be designed? In the same manner?

Comment: @TristanMzr Have a look at past questions to see if it's a duplicate. If not, that is a great question. I'm sure there will be a good fast answer. Maybe that would be a better template for your DeathStar artwork.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, why not design the *gore* stickers without the dimple? Then apply a single round sticker for the dimple over the other stickers.

I'm not sure what your death star is made from, but you could also cut the dimple part flat and at the same time cut out the gore stickers in a circle where the dimple will be applied.